# Infinite Longlistselector

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I want to implement infinite scroll to a webclient uri download. But i can not find a working example for longlist selector.

Currently my longlistselector lists limited number of results, if i can implement php pages to query how can i do this in windows phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [sample from Microsoft](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e). It is a twitter example that has infinite scrolling.

In the sample, they listen to the ItemRealized event to load more items from the viewmodel. The viewmodel then adds items to the end of an observable collection.

```
void resultListBox_ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (!_viewModel.IsLoading && resultListBox.ItemsSource != null &&
```

resultListBox.ItemsSource.Count

> = _offsetKnob) 
>               { 
>                   if (e.ItemKind == LongListSelectorItemKind.Item) 
>                   { 
>                       if ((e.Container.Content as
>   TwitterSearchResult).Equals(resultListBox. 
>   ItemsSource[resultListBox.ItemsSource.Count - _offsetKnob])) 
>                       { 
>                           Debug.WriteLine("Searching for {0}", _pageNumber); 
>                           _viewModel.LoadPage(_searchTerm, _pageNumber++); 
>                       } 
>                   } 
>               } 
>           }

Comment: the example not working i dont understand

Comment: Warning 1 Could not load the assembly file:///C:\Users\DC\Desktop\New folder (2)\TwitterSample\ExternalAssemblies\System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web.  If an assembly has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more informat,, i ve unblocked dll